# Why does rEFInd not allow to change theme?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, themes, refind

rEFInd is properly installed and up & running. 
I followed this method:

```
mkdir /Volumes/efi
```

Then mounted:

```
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/efi
```

Then  I created a `themes` folder in Efi/refind/ folder and copied the theme folder there `refind-ambience-master` into there.
I triggered the settings:

```
 echo "include rEFInd-minimal-master/theme.conf" >> refind.conf
```

And when I reboot the computer it instead of changing theme showing a zoomed background with less options/buttons:

[image: boot-screen]

Why does refind not change the theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `theme.conf` file in the Ambience theme is hard-coded to look for files in the `themes\refind-ambience` subdirectory of the main rEFInd directory on the ESP; however, it sounds like you renamed this directory to either `themes\refind-ambience-master` or `themes\rEFInd-minimal-master` (you refer to both locations). You must either use the directory names specified by the theme's author or update `theme.conf` to match your own names. If you change the directory name without updating `theme.conf`, then only the parts of `theme.conf` that do *not* refer to those directories will take effect. These include `banner_scale fillscreen`, which causes the banner to fill the screen; and a couple of options to hide most UI elements aside from the OS selectors. You will *not* get the updated banner (background image) or changed icons.